# 2d sprite animator, need overlay sprite to transition instantly

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am animating a 2d game and what I want to do is rather simple. I have some hand drawn sprite sheets with frame by frame animation of say attack, idle, run, die etc. where each animations will have approximately 8-10 drawings.

Now this has all worked perfectly and they are scripted and working exactly like I want them to. My problem is that now I wanted to add customization to my characters by overlaying, say a sword, on-top of the original sprite. So I added a sword to the game object and frame-by=frame animated it so that it will perfectly match the correct position in each frame. to a point where I can get the wanted result by dragging the red line (animating) across all the frames. However when I press "play" the sword does not snap from one position to the next but rather smoothly transitions from one position to the next revealing the original sprite underneath and ruining the animation entirely.

How do I make it so that the overlay (sword) transitions instantly, or "snaps" from one position/rotation x,y,z to the next position/rotation x,y,z?

**Things I have tried:**

**=** Making all of the curves of the overlay "sword" (both tangents: constant) However all this does is make the "curve" constant, and therefore of course does not work

**=** I tried reading http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EditingCurves.html but the only hack I thought of there for this was to just add keys and manually do all the keys, but no keys can be added between frames only at frames so I can not even hack it this way.

**=** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HM17mAmLd7k tried following this video and making my entire character this way, and although this works it really detracts from the "hand drawn" animation and leaves me with a style I don't much like.

I am at a loss as to what to do if I wish to animate this way and I am unsure if this is even possible, although if it isn't I cant understand why as this is a great way to get complex 2d animations that are very easily customizable.

ps: *These are NOT states, I know how to instantly transition between states it is in the actual animator.*

Thank you very much, my first question in here hope it isn't to silly, but I really have tried a lot before coming here an used many hours googling of course to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I have found a hack but I cannot understand how to do this correctly so the answer still stands for someone to come with a correct answer which Ill vote up.

I simply upped the frame rate to 90 instead of 9 which I was using and positioned the frame there correctly, when then returning to 9 frames per second it changes instantly as it is trying to animate the transition at 90 frames per second. I'm think that this is a bug in unity that requires a hack to get the desired effect, but please correct me if I am wrong.

if not perhaps this hack can help others.

Thank you.